# How I can make hexagons stack like a honeycomb?

Tags: css

How I can make hexagons stack like a honeycomb? My hexagon only have 3-4 hexagon.

This is code of my hexagon.

```
.hexagon {
    position: relative;
    clip-path: polygon(24% 3%, 72% 3%, 100% 50%, 74% 96%, 25% 96%, 0% 50%);
    background: rgb(193, 193, 209);
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hexagonal CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277743/hexagonal-css-background)

Comment: read this: https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/